# Site Footer is not showing up in mobile devices

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, mobile, mobile-view, footer

We have a publishing site in SharePoint Online and we created a SPFx extension that basically just injects this css:

```
div[class^="simpleFooterContainer-"] {
  height: 80px;
  background: #333333 url('${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/SiteAssets/Logo.png') no-repeat center center;background-size: auto 42px;
}
```

It works well on every desktop browser; however, it does not work on any mobile browser. In fact the footer doesn't even exist for mobile.

Side note: What we want is a footer that scrolls with the page, not a sticky footer.

Anyone know how to accomplish that in any browser, including iPhone and android mobile device browsers (Chrome and Safari)?

Comment: Are you using a modern SharePoint site?

Comment: yes, this is a modern site. For some reason there is no footer on mobile browsers.

Comment: It's not clear whether this is by design or a bug. Since the rendering of the footer is an out of the box feature, you could report this to Microsoft via a service request. This can be done via the admin portal or phone.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: yeah probably by design. Maybe I'll try to create a footer programatically and try to append it in the end of the page